# How to fetch taken screenShot?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am running through a small problem. I am able to take screen shot of my game through this code

```
+(UIImage*) screenshotWithStartNode:(CCNode*)startNode
{
[CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

CGSize winSize1 = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
CCRenderTexture* rtx =
[CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize1.width
                                 height:winSize1.height];
[rtx begin];
[startNode visit];
[rtx end];

return [rtx getUIImage];
}
```

Now I need to fetch the taken screen shot and later share it on social networking websites... I know it is possible through iPhone sdk but is it possible through cocos2d?

If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS7 there is a new api in UIKit that lets you take a screenshot very quickly.

UIView *screenshot =  [myView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];

This screenshot is now stored in this screenshot variable.

Comment: I think i am unable to properly tell my problem... i can take screen shot. I need to show that screenshot and then ask user if he wants to share it on facebook or twitter... That is i want to display that screenshot within game like it does in hill climbing and then use it for sharing and all....